# google play services 8.3.0 - get g+ cover image ( deprecated Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson() )

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

How can I get cover image after g+ login with google play services?

With previous play services version `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson().getCover()` worked fine but now this method is deprecated and `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson()` returns `null`. I request profile scope and `Plus.API`

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestProfile()
        //.requestIdToken()
        .requestEmail()
        .requestScopes(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE, new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"))
        .build();
// [END configure_signin]

// [START build_client]
// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .build();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add an OAuth key? create the OAuth constant screen as well. I got the result only after adding this

Answer (score -1):

Hello i have find Way for latest google plus login use **below method:-**

```
  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private void latestGooglePlus() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile().requestEmail().requestScopes(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE, new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"))
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .build();


    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, YOURREQUESTCODE);
}
```

And on **Activity result** use below code :-

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("Activity Res", "" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == YOURREQUESTCODE) {

        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
             GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            acct.getPhotoUrl();
            acct.getId();
            Log.e(TAG, acct.getDisplayName());
            Log.e(TAG, acct.getEmail());


            Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, "signed_in_user_account_id").setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
                     PersonBuffer personBuffer = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer();
                    if (personBuffer != null && personBuffer.getCount() > 0) {
                        Person currentUser = personBuffer.get(0);
                        personBuffer.release();
                        Person.Cover cover = currentUser.getCover();
                        if (cover != null) {
                            Person.Cover.CoverPhoto coverPhoto = cover.getCoverPhoto();
                            if (coverPhoto != null) {
                                String userCoverPhotoUrl = coverPhoto.getUrl();
                                Log.i("Main TAG", "Cover photo Url :" + userCoverPhotoUrl);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("TAG NO COVER", "Person has no cover");
                        }
                    }
            });
        }


    }  
}
```

**Finally you onclick will be :-**

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.txtGooglePlus:
            latestGooglePlus();
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```